# How to sanitize/disallow SSI directives in HTML files

Tags: html, web, sanitize, ssi

Is there a way to sanitize/disallow all SSI directives except what is already coded into the html files? I'm trying to prevent potential SSI injections. I can't seem to find any information on this.

Comment: How do you think would they get injected?

Comment: I'm think through forms or through the http headers?

Comment: No.  It doesn't work that way.  SSI is handled by Apache when the SHTML file is read from disk, similar to PHP.  Once it's in the browser, SSI is no longer relevant.  This can't happen.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info., So is there a way to properly sanitize/prevent/secure SSI injection vulnerabilities without having to just disable them or restricting it by user?

Comment: I don't believe there is any such thing as an "SSI injection vulnerability".  If you have a reference that shows I am wrong, I would like to read it.

Comment: To put it into reference, this is the message from a scanner used: The following resources may be vulnerable to SSI injection (on HTTP headers) : /RERTR37/index.shtml